# PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю сайт, не могу подключиться к базе. 
Код

```
 define("DB_HOSTNAME", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB_DATABASE", "objects");
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

Comment: Неправильный пароль Обычно локально пароля нет, объявите пароль так `define("DB_PASSWORD", "");`

Comment: Не помогло, все равно access denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась созданием юзера в mysql, прописанием ему * привелегий, и подключением через него.